# I want to support my app into 2.3 and upper version

Tags: android, android-library

I have created an app in Android 4.1 jelly bean, And I have used action bar and action bar sliding drawer, and I want to support my this app in Android 2.3 ginger bread and upper version. I know that I have to use some library, but I am confused that which library I have to use for this, I am new to use of libraries, I have used in google map once, but no deep knowledge about this.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need support libraries, they come with the SDK you have downloaded.

For action bar you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or use `getSupportActionBar()` from google in [your v7 compatibility jar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: i have downloaded Android support library from SDK Manager and ActionBarSherlock library., now please guide me, what to do ahead,?

Comment: check Vyger's link, it will help you out

Answer (score 1):

In you manifest, set `minSdkVersion = 9` and `targetSdkVersion = 19`

To add Fragments, the Navigation Drwawer, etc: add the support Library to your project.

If you also need the ActionBar, then add the [ActionBarSherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or the [actionBarCompat library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActionbarCompat` library.

See these links-

1. https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
2. http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/